# Word Template Linked to Excel

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

I have an Access database that creates a Word document based on a Word template.  In that template are a bunch of Charts, which in order to change their data, I have to programmatically launch an instance of Excel for each chart, change the data, then update.  This is not only distracting as it flashes each Excel worksheet up on the screen then disappears, but it's incredible slow.

It would be great if the Word template could be linked to an Excel workbook where each chart is linked to that one workbook.  Then, I could update the Excel file and the Word doc separately.  Much faster.

The problem is, I would require there to be a separate Excel file for each Word doc.  Basically I'd need a Word template to link to an Excel TEMPLATE.  Then when the new Word doc is created from it's template, it's linked Excel stuff is linked to a new Excel file based on an Excel template.

Does this make sense?  I just can't all Word docs linked to a single Excel file.

Thoughts?

Comment: Wow... no comments....

Comment: well... except for mine... :-)